# Android Studio generated Navigation Drawer Activity - problem

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-studio-3.5.3

Using Android Studio 3.5.3. Generated standard Navigation Drawer Activity app - no change to any of the defaults.
Built and ran ok on Pixel3a.

Added values-v28 styles.xml to add the following

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

Built and ran again. Edge to edge in Landscape either direction as you would expect.

Simulate Corner Cutout via developer options. The attached image (rotated right) demonstrates the problem. All OK in portrait. Similiar problem rotated left landscape but in reverse. Could someone advise how to correct the appbar/toolbar and contents of the fragment to enable it to expand edge to edge? Statusbar does is doing it fine.

The attached image from AS cuts off a little of the right-hand side. But on the device, you can see the Statusbar has gone edge to edge, but the image doesn't show the rounded corner and the black hole of the corner cutout at the bottom right is not captured. If in doubt about the photo just take a couple of seconds and generate an app.

I've done this before with the old support libs and Android 9 and have never seen this problem before.

[image: Pixel3a image]